# SQL Loader - Invalid Number

Tags: sql, oracle, loading, sql-loader

I'm trying to load data via SQLoader, but it gives me error at the numeric field of Invalid Number

My Data File:

```
00163604~12002~S~N~N~Panasonic Juicer 1.5l Steel Color~ss~E~A~12/15/2014 3:33:57 PM~N~N~N~Y~294~SA
```

Control File:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE "/home/dmf/ITEMLOC.txt"
APPEND
INTO TABLE DMF.MIG_ITEM_LC
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "~"
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
ITEM "SUBSTRB(:ITEM,1,25)",
LOC "TO_NUMBER(:LOC)",
LOC_TYPE "SUBSTRB(:LOC_TYPE,1,1)",
CLEAR_IND "SUBSTRB(:CLEAR_IND,1,1)",
TAXABLE_IND "SUBSTRB(:TAXABLE_IND,1,1)",
LOCAL_ITEM_DESC "SUBSTRB(:LOCAL_ITEM_DESC,1,250)",
LOCAL_SHORT_DESC "SUBSTRB(:LOCAL_SHORT_DESC,1,120)",
STORE_ORD_MULT "SUBSTRB(:STORE_ORD_MULT,1,1)",
STATUS_UPDATE_DATE sysdate,
STATUS "SUBSTRB(:STATUS,1,1)",
STORE_PRICE_IND "SUBSTRB(:STORE_PRICE_IND,1,1)",
RPM_IND "SUBSTRB(:RPM_IND,1,1)",
EXT_UIN_IND "SUBSTRB(:EXT_UIN_IND,1,1)",
RANGED_IND "SUBSTRB(:RANGED_IND,1,1)",
PRIMARY_SUPP "TO_NUMBER(:PRIMARY_SUPP)",  -- The Error is coming here
PRIMARY_CNTRY "SUBSTRB(:PRIMARY_CNTRY,1,3)"
)
```

Rejected - Error on table DMF.MIG_ITEM_LC, column PRIMARY_SUPP.
ORA-01722: invalid number

If i write give constant to it, it loads successfully.

What could be the issue?

Comment: How is the PRIMARY_SUPP column defined in the database?  Does it fail on all rows or just certain rows? Could the data contain a control character that is not visible?  Oh and make sure none of your description columns contain your delimiter as that will throw everything off by a column.

Comment: It's defined as NUMBER in the database. 
and none of the description has the delimiter. 

When I give it a constant PRIMARY_SUPP CONSTANT '2', it gets loaded. but not with the value in the data file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data as posted loads fine for me.

```
SQL> select version from v$instance;

VERSION
-----------------
11.2.0.2.0
```

Here's the create table statement I used:

```
create table test1
(
item varchar2(25),
loc number,
loc_type char(1),
clear_ind char(1),
taxable_ind char(1),
local_item_desc varchar2(250),
local_short_desc varchar2(120),
store_ord_mult char(1),
status char(1),
store_price_ind char(1),
rpm_ind char(1),
ext_uin_ind char(1),
ranged_ind char(1),
primary_supp number,
primary_cntry varchar2(3)
);
```

If you get this error while trying to load only the one record that you posted, then I would suspect an unprintable character, like @Gary_W suggested.  View the data with a hex viewer to check.

A character set difference between the file and your NLS_LANG setting could be at fault, but I doubt it in this case, since your data looks to be all ASCII values.

Comment: Thanks Russell, 
I just figured out that I was reading one of the date value from the data file for which I was also inserting sysdate. So it inserted the sysdate for that variable and pushed the data from the file to next variable. (updated control file)

Just another question, 
is there any way to read the record from the datafile, and not use that value, instead use a constant value?

Comment: The simplest way in this case would be to just move your STATUS_UPDATE_DATE column to the end of the sqlldr control file, where Oracle will pretend there's an extra field in the data since you used the TRAILING NULLCOLS option.